# capture process cannot access

Tags: file, batch-file, windows-xp, ingres

There is the following line command:

> statdump -zdl %db% > "%ckpdb_dir%"\statdump_%db%.log

the result of the Statdump is sent to the log file, but I would like that if there is some error, for example that the statdump is being used already by another process, and then I get the message "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by anoter process on the screen, but I would like to capture these message in a file.

I tried with:

> statdump -zdl %db% > "%ckpdb_dir%"\statdump_%db%.log > ckpdb.log

but is not the solution...

btw there is no error generated when happen this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
statdump -zdl %db% -o "%ckpdb_dir%\statdump_%db%.log" 2> error.log
```

Comment: the "-o" flag doesn't work like you thought, it writes in the db.log file the correct sintax to use with the statdump (so error)

Comment: maybe I think this happen only when a direct the output into a file, because in this case only one process can write into it

Answer (score 0):

You want to redirect stderr somewhere else than stdout like this:

```
statdump -zdl %db% >"%ckpdb_dir%\statdump_%db%.log" 2>err.log
```

The last part redirects stderr to the file err.log.

Comment: I have runned the line into a batch file, together with the same file in another terminal command of windows, but the message is shown instead that written into the err.log :(

Comment: @aemme Could you explain better what you got in the err.log using this?

Comment: This command illustrates the principle: "xcopy sdfjls >log.txt 2>err.txt". It creates both files, log.txt and err.txt, one with output from stdout and the other with output from stderr.

Comment: also because the %errorlevel% is managed after tah line, but this emssage is given with %errorlevel% = 0....

Comment: yes the sterr works perfectly but the message I told you is always shown in the monitor...